# Stop one type of user from logging into app firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two apps that share the same backend but want presented in the app space as two separate apps. I have one for the users and the other for admin of my company. Both apps have completely different functions but need to access info from the same database. I am storying my users in my firebase database like:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "Admin" : {
      "OStVNPELMvVlu9JIQ3UttsDMpJK2" : {
        "Name" : "Dave",
        },
      "ZtfDN0gou8Qe6csrwcaKaVzgeUT2" : {
        "Name" : "Matthew",
        }
    },
    "People" : {
      "ED2RLbhJJrhX4CTl4iVRUjo1VkM2" : {
        "Name" : "Kathy",
      },
      "arBssUBJaHXyU6G7roWI6miWri22" : {
        "Name" : "Kate",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then have a function for logging them in that isn't working due to ambiguity but I think that it is a decent start to figuring out my problem. It looks like:

```
@IBAction func LogInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // TODO: Validate Text Fields

    // Create cleaned versions of the text field
    let email = EmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    // Signing in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Couldn't sign iner
            self.ErrorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else  {
            
            if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == Database.database().reference().child("Users").child("Admin").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid) {
            
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainTBC", sender: nil)
        }
            
            else {
                
                self.ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
                self.ErrorLabel.text = "No account found"
                
            }
            
            }

        }
}
```

I really need to apps to be separate as I have spent months with both being separated and want to keep it that way. I also don't want to necessarily change my database because I have various functions set up based on the above JSON tree. There has to be a way to restrict the one type of users from accessing the one app. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer to my problem. One problem I was running into after figuring out how to verify if the user was admin, was when they clicked on forgot password. It would take them to another view controller and then when presented to the login view controller it would keep them logged in and give them access to the app. My following code was able to fix the problem while maintaining my database the way I wanted it:

```
@IBAction func LogInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // TODO: Validate Text Fields

    // Create cleaned versions of the text field
    let email = EmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    // Signing in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Couldn't sign iner
            self.ErrorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else  {
            
            let UID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid as String
            
            var currentUser = ""
            
            Database.database().reference().child("Users").child("Admin").child(UID).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                
                let user = UserSignIn(from: snapshot)
                let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                
                user?.UID = dictionary?["UID"] as? String
                
                currentUser.append((user?.UID) ?? "")
                
                if UID == currentUser {
                    
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainTBC", sender: nil)
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    
                    self.ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.ErrorLabel.text = "No account found"
                    
                    do{
                               
                               try Auth.auth().signOut()
                           } catch let logoutError {
                               print(logoutError)
                           }
                    
                }
                
               }
            }

        }
}
```

I needed to also create a class that could download the UID with nil so it could be checked for my if else statement. The way I fixed the still logging in when reopened or transitioning back to the login view controller was by forcing the app to sign the user out on the device so it wouldn't recognize them.

Here is the class:

```
class UserSignIn: NSObject {
var UID: String?

init?(from snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
    
        self.UID = dictionary?["UID"] as? String
    
    }
}
```

I had a great time figuring this out and I hope that it helps someone in the future!